# WIFI keeps disconnecting on 22.04.3 LTS after "apt upgrade" from 6.2.0-39-generic to 6.5.0-14-generic

Tags: networking, upgrade

Before `apt upgrade`, `uname -a => 6.2.0-39-generic`. Actual result - wifi stable
After  `apt upgrade`, `uname -a => 6.5.0-14-generic`. Actual result - wifi keeps dropping

Other details:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.2.0-39-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
---
Jan 17 06:51:49 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.6412] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.6435] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.co>
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.6845] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jan 17 06:51:49 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.7109] manager[0x558933c32000]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.7114] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8656] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8656] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "<censored>"
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8702] dns-mgr[0x558933c0c2a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8731] rfkill3: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill3) (driver mt7921e)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8732] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/platform/acer-wmi/rfkill/rfkill0) (platform driver acer-wmi)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8794] manager[0x558933c32000]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8795] manager[0x558933c32000]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.8900] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9022] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9150] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9364] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9396] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9400] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9401] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9401] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9574] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9576] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9585] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9596] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9735] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9736] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9738] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9752] manager: (enp1s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9762] settings: (enp1s0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jan 17 06:51:49 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492309.9763] device (enp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.2353] device (wlp2s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.2357] manager: (wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.2358] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9051] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9149] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9484] manager: (virbr0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9615] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9616] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp2s0 created
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9617] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9619] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9621] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:50 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492310.9625] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2139] device (virbr0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2143] device (virbr0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2150] device (virbr0): Activation: starting connection 'virbr0' (40317e6e-7c5a-46a8-81ea-320c6cf1cdce)
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2166] device (virbr0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2171] device (virbr0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2175] device (virbr0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2188] device (virbr0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2228] device (virbr0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2230] device (virbr0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2232] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 17 06:51:51 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492311.2234] device (virbr0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 17 06:51:52 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492312.2867] agent-manager: agent[86e4784af252d22c,:1.33/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/125]: agent registered
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8445] policy: auto-activating connection '<censored>' (ea92f47b-5b1c-477b-b438-c76290c37e6e)
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8451] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection '<censored>' (ea92f47b-5b1c-477b-b438-c76290c37e6e)
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8453] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8454] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8455] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8457] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point '<censored>' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8458] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8464] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8465] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8467] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection '<censored>' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8467] Config: added 'ssid' value '<censored>'
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8467] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8467] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8467] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8467] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8468] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8738] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8738] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8768] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 17 06:51:57 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492317.8768] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 17 06:51:58 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492318.3936] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 17 06:51:58 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492318.3936] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Jan 17 06:51:58 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492318.9105] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Jan 17 06:51:58 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492318.9106] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0122] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0122] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "<censored>"
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0123] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0125] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0138] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0347] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.50.112
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0415] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0448] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0451] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0456] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0465] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0466] policy: set '<censored>' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0475] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0484] manager: startup complete
Jan 17 06:51:59 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.1566] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan 17 06:52:04 NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492324.8115] agent-manager: agent[53c7b89dd7cc18e3,:1.86/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered

service NetworkManager status
---
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-17 06:51:49 EST; 17min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 608 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 13982)
     Memory: 11.6M
        CPU: 369ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─608 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0415] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0448] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0451] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0456] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0465] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0466] policy: set '<censored>' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0475] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.0484] manager: startup complete
Jan 17 06:51:59 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492319.1566] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan 17 06:52:04 <censored>NetworkManager[608]: <info>  [1705492324.8115] agent-manager: agent[53c7b89dd7cc18e3,:1.86/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered

service --status-all
---
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ - ]  lvm2
 [ - ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio-enable-autospawn
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ + ]  smartmontools
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ - ]  sysstat
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a static IP address for your Ubuntu machine in both the router and the Ubuntu settings? Sometimes using a single, manually assigned, local IP address provides a more stable connection as there's no DHCP lease to negotiate and/or renegotiate.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: @waltinator done

Comment: Notice that your `journalctl ` output is truncated on the right, losing needed information. Rerun the command in a wider terminal.

Comment: output looks good to me. What's the # of line that's truncated for you?

Comment: What is your processor? I have a suspicion it has to do with AMD power management.

Comment: Intel i3. Never mind, this guessing game isn't leading to an outcome. I'll just roll back to 6.2.0.39

Comment: It's not a guessing game for me. I'm compiling custom kernels until I find the version that causes the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubuntu 22.04 - wifi freeze after hwe kernel upgrade to 6.5 (was fine on 6.2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499938/kubuntu-22-04-wifi-freeze-after-hwe-kernel-upgrade-to-6-5-was-fine-on-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of the exact kernel version I was using, but with the same MT7921 card on some WLANs only I was rarely able to connect, until it was suggested I upgrade from 22.04.3 LTS to 23.10 which resolved all issues. Separate issue, but if you do upgrade, I noticed my 23.10 system because very sluggish only after a recent kernel update so I downgrade to 6.5.0-21-generic for the moment which restored normal performance.

I had issues with the same card on some WLANs until it was suggested I upgrade from 22.04 to 23.10 which resolved all issues. Separate issue but I noticed my 23.10 system because very sluggish only after a recent kernel upgrade so I fixed it to Linux 6.5.0-21-generic for the moment which resolved that.

[Mediatek MT7921 WLAN stuck on connecting, or no/intermittent pages display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487220/mediatek-mt7921-wlan-stuck-on-connecting-or-no-intermittent-pages-display?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C0.0000)