# Dual Boot Windows10/Ubuntu 22.04 WiFi Constantly turns off/on. Connection is much worse compared to Windows. Ideapad 5 16ACH6. Network Adapter: MT7921

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 22.04, lenovo, windows-10

I have been beaten. Went over hundreds of possible solutions and nothing worked as I wanted it too. Including starting completely from the beginning.

As described in the title I have setup a dual boot on an Lenovo Ideapad Creator 5 16ACH6

With a network card output of: `sudo  lshw -C network`

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 10:6f:d9:36:8b:0f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.5.0-18-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.0.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:86 memory:fc02000000-fc020fffff memory:fc02100000-fc02103fff memory:fc02104000-fc02104fff
```

Output of: `uname -a`

```
Linux Ivan 6.5.0-18-generic #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 11:40:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of: `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Gold P31 SSD
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c5)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
06:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
06:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

Extra info:

Windows's fast start up is disabled.

BIOS Fast Boot is disabled.

Ubuntu has been ran from a completely powered off state multiple times.

Problem described: WiFi on Ubuntu is noticeably slower and response times are much bigger. In intervals of about 15min the WiFi cuts off for about 30 seconds. To me it seems like the network card stops working. WiFi setup is 2.4GHz and 5GHz two bands set up with different names so I doubt that the system is trying to jump between networks.

I am not that keen on having a 5GHz connection. But I want it to be stable. That is my goal.

I would appreciate your help a lot since I have been battling this monster for about 20 hours now in the span of 2 days.

If you need any other information let me know :)

Comment: I don't care if I have tried something already I am ready to try it out again give suggestions.

Comment: Wifi power management been disabled in Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubuntu 22.04 - wifi freeze after hwe kernel upgrade to 6.5 (was fine on 6.2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499938/kubuntu-22-04-wifi-freeze-after-hwe-kernel-upgrade-to-6-5-was-fine-on-6-2)